# Visual Studio - Package Manager Console - Running commands programmatically

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, powershell, package-managers

Every time I update the production website, I need to run 5 commands, who only differ by a name.

I'd like to automatize this (in the future, it could be I have to run these commands 100 times for example).

What I do is:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration" -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=PC-1\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Database1;uid=prog;password=ndp103@50;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" 
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration" -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=PC-1\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Database2;uid=prog;password=ndp103@50;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" 
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration" -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=PC-1\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Database3;uid=prog;password=ndp103@50;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" 
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration" -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=PC-1\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Database4;uid=prog;password=ndp103@50;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient" 
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration" -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=PC-1\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=Database5;uid=prog;password=ndp103@50;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

How could I write i script, so that, when I type in the console manager:

```
Update-Database -type Production -version latest
```

It runs all the commands above, without any interference. (All connectionstrings are located in an .XML file like:

```
 <databases>
    <type>Production
        <database>Database1</database>
        <database>Database2</database>
        <database>Database3</database>
        <database>Database4</database>
        <database>Database5</database>
    </type>
 </databases>
```

Comment: Because the Package Manager Console is a PowerShell host you can write a PowerShell script for your logic.

Comment: I had Powershell as tag in the question, but i had forgotten to mention PowerShell in my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about the package manager console per se, but if the goal is to read a bunch of database names out of an XML, pop them into a connection string, and pass them to a cmdlet, below should get you going:

```
$config = [xml](gc c:\path\to\config.xml)
$dbNames= $config.Databases.Type.Database

$dbNames|%{
  $connStr = "Server=PC-1\SQLEXPRESS;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=$_;uid=prog;password=ndp103@50;"
  Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration" -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose -ConnectionString $connStr -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
}
```

Comment: I used this solution. It's the closest to what i wanted.

And it works, thx!

Comment: @latkin : "I don't know anything about the package manager console per se", The Package Manager Console is a PowerShell console within Visual Studio used to interact with NuGet and automate Visual Studio.

Comment: @NicoJuicy How could you manage to use the multiline `{` construct in Package Manager Console? I do know the ctrl+shift+enter is working to add continuation line, but I suppose you have a prewritten script to copy and paste...

Comment: @g.pickardou It's a powershell script. The powershell script can be called through Package Manager Console

Comment: @NicoJuicy many thx, I concluded the same, so there is an extra hop, outsource the code to a .ps1 file and call the script from PM>

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, you're simply asking how to write and execute a powershell script from within the package manager console.

1) Create a new script in the current directory with notepad:

```
notepad newScript.ps1
```

2) Paste your commands into notepad

```
Update-Database...
Update-Datebase...
Update-Database...
```

3) Save the notepad file

4) Execute the notepad file by typing this into the package manager console:

```
.\newScript.ps1
```

Note that the use of powershell functions and parameters are beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: After execute "newScript.ps1" this error occurred : `The term 'Update-Database' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` How to solve it?

Comment: The package of Entity Framework can't be found ( a bit late to the party, sorry)